# Junit testing for following scenario

Tags: java, junit, testcase

Consider the following class

```
public class Validator {

    boolean startValiadation(UserBean user){  
        //This method is visible inside this package only        
        return validateUser(user);           
    }

    private static boolean validateUser(UserBean user){
        //This method is visible inside this class only  
        boolean result=false;
        //validations here
        return result;
    }
}
```

Due to security requirement of above method I did code in above way. Now I want to wrote test cases using `Junit`. But generally a unit test is intended to exercise the public interface of a class or unit. Still I can use `reflection` to do some thing what I am expecting here. But I want to know is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? This code doesn't do anything useful: the only accessible method has no return value, and doesn't have any side effect. Also, accessibility of methods is not a way to improve security. It helps in design and encapsulation. Any method, even private, can be called with reflection.

Comment: @JBNizet There could be exceptions thrown inside `validateUser` if the user doesn't meet certain conditions.

Comment: Then OP can just test `startValiadation()`: the exceptions will be propagated.

Comment: @JBNizet There are relevant logic to validate user inside the `validateUser` method. you want to see them too?

Comment: @Ruchira: whatever the logic is, if you ignore the result of this logic in startValidation(), this validation logic is useless (unless the aim is to throw exceptions, but then why return a boolean?).

Comment: @JBNizet I edited the question to reduce confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But generally a unit test is intended to exercise the public interface of a class or unit.

Well, I don't get too dogmatic about that. I find that often you can get much better testing depth if you're willing to be "white box" about it, and test non-public members. There's a sliding scale though - testing *private* members directly is relatively ugly, but you can test *package private* methods easily, just by making sure your test is in the same package as the class.

(This approach also encourages package private classes - I find that if you're rigidly sticking to testing *just* the public API, you often end up getting into the habit of making all classes public and many methods public when actually they should be package private.)

In this case, I would suggest you test via the `startValiadation` method. Currently that calls  `validateUser` but ignores the result - I would assume that in the real code it calls the method and does something *useful* with the result, which would be visible from the test. In that case, you can just call `startValiadation` with various different `User` objects and assert which ones should be valid.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need reflection.  Just put your test class in the same package as this class.  It doesn't need to be in the same folder or the same project to do that.

Comment: @DavidWallance, I think you are not getting my point correct. Still I can't wrote a test case for `private` method. also according to the package structure there is a separate package for test cases.

Comment: @Ruchira: that's the problem, and the solution is in David's answer: don't put test cases in a separate package. Put them in the same package as the class under test. That's the usual practice anyway, and one of the reasons is precisely to be able to test package-protected and protected methods.

Comment: @Ruchira - I thought you were looking to test the `startValiadation` method.  Is there a reason why you want to test `validateUser` as well?  Won't testing just one of them suffice?

Comment: @DavidWallace Since all business logic to validate user contains `validateUser` method. That's why i need to test it

Comment: @Ruchira: startValidation() does a single thing: calling validateUser(). So if you test startValiadation(), you'll test validateUser(). BTW, You could simply remove this private method and inline it into startValiadation(), since startValidation() doesn't add anything.

Comment: OK, I've said it before and I'll say it again. I don't entirely agree with Jon Skeet (actually, I just like saying that :-). You SHOULD be VERY dogmatic about the relationship between the access modifier of a method, and what kind of test you should write. All tests should be based on the fulfilment of some part of a contract.  This class fulfils a contract to other classes in the same package, via the `startValidation` method. You should be able to derive test cases from the terms of that contract. The `validateUser` method is not part of the contract between this class and any other, so, ...

Comment: ... like every other private method of every other class, it does not need to be tested, and SHOULD NOT be tested.

Answer (score 0):

No you have only three choices to test a private method:

1. If you are in control of the code, then change the access specifier to public just to test the method
2. Otherwise use reflection.

This may be of your interest:

3 . Use a public method to test your private method.

Comment: But the OP presumably wants the test to call `startValiadation`, not `validateUser`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't test this class in isolation.  A unit test, at least in the spirit of TDD as envisioned by Kent Beck, is not a test for a single class or method, but is simply a test that cannot have side effects on other tests.

This `Validator` class is used in other classes within the same package.  First write a failing test using the public interface of those classes, then make it pass by implementing the validation.  No reflection needed.

If you would test this class in isolation, you would probably mock this class in the other classes and verify that `startValiadation()` is really called.  This has the disadvantage of coupling your test code to your implementation code.  I would say: don't do that.

I recently wrote a [post](http://www.hermansjavablog.eu/automated-testing/tdd-avoid-coupling-implementation-to-test-code/) about this, at the bottom there's a link to a presentation by Ian Cooper that goes deeper into this.